# VBA MsgBox Yes/No

Tags: excel, vba, msgbox

When I select No in my message box prompt, the document still closes. I want it to stay open when i select no. I'm not sure how to do this. Thanks.

```
Option Explicit

Sub b()

 'declares docX as a document and stores it
  Dim docX As Documents
 'opens the document file
  Application.Documents.Open FileName:="C:\Users\johnr\OneDrive\Documents\CIS 208 VBA\Rimando_Input_Box.docm"

'prompts the user to select either Yes or No
 MsgBox Prompt:="Close document?", _
     Buttons:=vbYesNo
'If the user selects the Yes button then the document closes without making save changes.
 If vbYes Then
     Application.ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdPromptToSaveChanges
 Else
     'Keep the document open
 End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

That would be because you didn't return your msgbox's value to a variable.

In this case, I would prefer not to use a variable but just a simple `Select Case` statement:

```
    Select Case MsgBox(Prompt:="Close document?", Buttons:=vbYesNo)
    Case vbYes
         Application.ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdPromptToSaveChanges
    Case vbNo
         'Keep the document open
    End Select
```

But I did notice another issue, you declared `docX` as type **documents**, you probably meant to use `Dim docX As Document` (no `s`). And then I also noticed that you didn't even use the variable.

See the following to correct those issues as well:

```
Sub b()

    Dim docX As Document
    Set docX = Application.Documents.Open( _
           Filename:="C:\Users\johnr\OneDrive\Documents\CIS 208 VBA\Rimando_Input_Box.docm")

    Select Case MsgBox(Prompt:="Close document?", Buttons:=vbYesNo)
    Case vbYes
         docX.Close SaveChanges:=wdPromptToSaveChanges
    Case vbNo
         'Keep the document open
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Awww I was going to propose `If MsgBox(Prompt:="Close document?", Buttons:=vbYesNo) = vbYes Then`... :)

Comment: Ha! - sorry :-)